# How to Draw 4 corner Edges center of device

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

I want to draw 4 Corner edges in center of the device using the canvas.

**Like this**

[image]

I am trying this

```
 Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawRect(
        getLeft()+(getRight()-getLeft())/4,
        getTop()+(getBottom()-getTop())/4,
        getRight()-(getRight()-getLeft())/4,
        getBottom()-(getBottom()-getTop())/3,myPaint);
```

**My result**

[image]

Comment: use [drawPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint) instead of drawRect.

Comment: use vector Drawable for this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40217644/6893465

Comment: ... or a simple 9 patch

Comment: Thanks... everyone... it was done with yours help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am draw this Using 9 Patch Image....

```
 Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_scanner_frame);
  paint.setColor(Color.RED);
  canvas.drawBitmap(b, width/2-b.getWidth()/2, height/2-b.getHeight()/2, paint);
```

[image]